# CSS - center a div inside of another div (non-nested)

Tags: html, css, center

I have 10 non-nested div elements, each decreasing in size. In the CSS file they all are set to "position: absolute". They end up inside of each other which is what I want, but they are not centered.

Is it even possible to center them inside of each other while they aren't nested? I tried "position: relative", but that didn't do anything.

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

div {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 3px;
}

#outer {
  background-color: thistle;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}

#outer1 {
  background-color: cyan;
  height: 190px;
  width: 190px;
  position: absolute;
}

#outer2 {
  background-color: darkcyan;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  position: absolute;
}

#outer3 {
  background-color: greenyellow;
  height: 170px;
  width: 170px;
  position: absolute;
}

#outer4 {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 160px;
  width: 160px;
  position: absolute;
}

#outer5 {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
}

#outer6 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  position: absolute;
}

#outer7 {
  background-color: azure;
  height: 130px;
  width: 130px;
  position: absolute;
}

#outer8 {
  background-color: mediumaquamarine;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  position: absolute;
}

#outer9 {
  background-color: salmon;
  height: 110px;
  width: 110px;
  position: absolute;
}

#outer0 {
  background-color: olive;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

#inner {
  background-color: lavender;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Innerconflict</title>
  <script src="innerconflict.js" defer></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="roundel_1.css">
</head>
<button>RESET</button>
<br>
<br>
<body>
  <div id="outer"> </div>
  <div id="outer2"> </div>
  <div id="outer3"> </div>
  <div id="outer4"> </div>
  <div id="outer5"> </div>
  <div id="outer6"> </div>
  <div id="outer7"> </div>
  <div id="outer8"> </div>
  <div id="outer9"> </div>
  <div id="outer0"> </div>
  <div id="inner"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you looking for a kind if shape ? i suspect we can do what you want easily with one div ---> as a side note: everything should be with the body tag

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to wrap them inside an `inline-block` element and remove `position:absolute` from the biggest one then you can easily center them:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.main>div:not(:first-child) {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
  position:absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#outer {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
  background-color: thistle;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

#outer1 {
  background-color: cyan;
  height: 190px;
  width: 190px;
}

#outer2 {
  background-color: darkcyan;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
}

#outer3 {
  background-color: greenyellow;
  height: 170px;
  width: 170px;
}

#outer4 {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 160px;
  width: 160px;
}

#outer5 {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

#outer6 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
}

#outer7 {
  background-color: azure;
  height: 130px;
  width: 130px;
}

#outer8 {
  background-color: mediumaquamarine;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
}

#outer9 {
  background-color: salmon;
  height: 110px;
  width: 110px;
}

#outer0 {
  background-color: olive;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

#inner {
  background-color: lavender;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div id="outer"> </div>
  <div id="outer2"> </div>
  <div id="outer3"> </div>
  <div id="outer4"> </div>
  <div id="outer5"> </div>
  <div id="outer6"> </div>
  <div id="outer7"> </div>
  <div id="outer8"> </div>
  <div id="outer9"> </div>
  <div id="outer0"> </div>
  <div id="inner"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you could center them with `calc`:

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

div {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 3px;
}
#inner {
  background-color: lavender;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 45px);
  top: calc(50% - 45px);
}

#outer1 {
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
  top: calc(50% - 100px);
}

#outer1 {
  background-color: cyan;
  height: 190px;
  width: 190px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 95px);
  top: calc(50% - 95px);
}

#outer2 {
  background-color: darkcyan;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 90px);
  top: calc(50% - 90px);
}

#outer3 {
  background-color: greenyellow;
  height: 170px;
  width: 170px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 85px);
  top: calc(50% - 85px);
}

#outer4 {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 160px;
  width: 160px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 80px);
  top: calc(50% - 80px);
}

#outer5 {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 75px);
  top: calc(50% - 75px);
}

#outer6 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 70px);
  top: calc(50% - 70px);
}

#outer7 {
  background-color: azure;
  height: 130px;
  width: 130px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 65px);
  top: calc(50% - 65px);
}

#outer8 {
  background-color: mediumaquamarine;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 60px);
  top: calc(50% - 60px);
}

#outer9 {
  background-color: salmon;
  height: 110px;
  width: 110px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 55px);
  top: calc(50% - 55px);
}

#outer10 {
  background-color: olive;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Innerconflict</title>
  <script src="innerconflict.js" defer></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="roundel_1.css">
</head>
<button>RESET</button>
<br>
<br>
<body>
  <div id="inner"> </div>
  <div id="outer1"> </div>
  <div id="outer2"> </div>
  <div id="outer3"> </div>
  <div id="outer4"> </div>
  <div id="outer5"> </div>
  <div id="outer6"> </div>
  <div id="outer7"> </div>
  <div id="outer8"> </div>
  <div id="outer9"> </div>
  <div id="outer10"> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

While css vars can't be incremented, the `counter-increment` can't be used as a property value and the `attr()` function isn't implemented yet, you still can use css to count elements with `:nth-child()`.

Also, depending on your needs, you can use a [css transformation](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) to avoid playing with margins & positions. The browser support [is very good](https://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d).

```css
div {
  background-color: gray;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: orange;
}

div:nth-child(1) {
  transform: scale(.95);
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  transform: scale(.9);
}

div:nth-child(3) {
  transform: scale(.85);
}

div:nth-child(4) {
  transform: scale(.8);
}

/* And so on... */
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need here is just a little margin added to the non-nested containers' CSS:

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

div {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 3px;
}

#outer {
  background-color: thistle;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}

#outer1 {
  background-color: cyan;
  height: 190px;
  width: 190px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}

#outer2 {
  background-color: darkcyan;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}

#outer3 {
  background-color: greenyellow;
  height: 170px;
  width: 170px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  position: absolute;
}

#outer4 {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 160px;
  width: 160px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}

#outer5 {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  position: absolute;
}

#outer6 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: absolute;
}

#outer7 {
  background-color: azure;
  height: 130px;
  width: 130px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: 35px;
  position: absolute;
}

#outer8 {
  background-color: mediumaquamarine;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  position: absolute;
}

#outer9 {
  background-color: salmon;
  height: 110px;
  width: 110px;
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-top: 45px;
  position: absolute;
}

#outer0 {
  background-color: olive;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#inner {
  background-color: lavender;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  margin-left: 55px;
  margin-top: 55px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Innerconflict</title>
  <script src="innerconflict.js" defer></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="roundel_1.css">
</head>
<button>RESET</button>
<br>
<br>
<body>
  <div id="outer"> </div>
  <div id="outer2"> </div>
  <div id="outer3"> </div>
  <div id="outer4"> </div>
  <div id="outer5"> </div>
  <div id="outer6"> </div>
  <div id="outer7"> </div>
  <div id="outer8"> </div>
  <div id="outer9"> </div>
  <div id="outer0"> </div>
  <div id="inner"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a simple alternative of Temani Afif's answer. It follows the same strategy as to wrap them all inside another div.

```
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

div {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 3px;
}
#outermost{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
#outer {
  background-color: thistle;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}

#outer1 {
  background-color: cyan;
  height: 190px;
  width: 190px;
  position: absolute;
}

#outer2 {
  background-color: darkcyan;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  position: absolute;
}

#outer3 {
  background-color: greenyellow;
  height: 170px;
  width: 170px;
  position: absolute;
}

#outer4 {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 160px;
  width: 160px;
  position: absolute;
}

#outer5 {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
}

#outer6 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  position: absolute;
}

#outer7 {
  background-color: azure;
  height: 130px;
  width: 130px;
  position: absolute;
}

#outer8 {
  background-color: mediumaquamarine;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  position: absolute;
}

#outer9 {
  background-color: salmon;
  height: 110px;
  width: 110px;
  position: absolute;
}

#outer0 {
  background-color: olive;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

#inner {
  background-color: lavender;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

We are using `display:flex` property to get our job done. HTML would look like

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Innerconflict</title>
  <script src="innerconflict.js" defer></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="roundel_1.css">
</head>
<button>RESET</button>
<br>
<br>
<body>
  <div id="outermost">
    <div id="outer"> </div>
    <div id="outer2"> </div>
    <div id="outer3"> </div>
    <div id="outer4"> </div>
    <div id="outer5"> </div>
    <div id="outer6"> </div>
    <div id="outer7"> </div>
    <div id="outer8"> </div>
    <div id="outer9"> </div>
    <div id="outer0"> </div>
    <div id="inner"> </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

If you need vertical alignment, all you need to do is add `align-items:center` to `#outermost` and remove absolute position in `#outer`. Hope this helps.

This is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/60Lmy30j/20/) for the vertical and horizontal alignment.